# Check if an inputream is empty

Tags: java, android, inputstream

In my application I use socket to communication with another device how I can check if `inputStream` is `empty` ? In this line I have a 
`java.net.SocketTimeoutException`

```
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(content)) != -1) {
```

Comment: Define 'empty'. The timeout has already told you there is no data available *now*, but that doesn't mean there never will be. There's generally no need to move beyond read timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Try `inputstream.available()`. It returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.

Comment: Read the javadoc of the method: "The available method for class InputStream always returns 0".